# Vba coding for pulling data through vlookup to master sheer from different worksheet with different tabs

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am new for vba coding

Suppose there is a master sheet name "MDS" and there is a different workbook with different tabs like 
Aon
Pge
Hilton
Hsbc

So i need to pull the data through vlook up in mastersheet of that particular tab

If i put aon it fetch aon data. Same goes with other client

Can you please help me with ths

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question.  For the best possible answers questions should be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have done to get to where you are now.  There is a [great article about how to write good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider having a read of it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: Apparently you merely need help understanding / using `VLookUp`. So, you might want to [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hJxIMBbmZY) and afterwards implement the requested formulas into your Excel file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Vlookup formula that references a different workbook, such as this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,[testOne.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5,2,0)
```

This would be the equivalent using VBA:

```
Sub UseVlookup_VBA()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks("testOne.xlsx")
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1:B5")

    Range("C1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A1"), rng, 2, 0)

End Sub
```